# String same multiple different number (PHP)

Tags: php, if-statement

I need help.
As I do?
String same other string with different number.
Example

```
if ($current_server == "Lobby-01") {
    echo "visiting in Lobby"
} elif ($current_server == "Lobby-02"){
    echo "visiting in Lobby"
} and more..
```

I thought about trying

```
if ($current_server == "Lobby-/[0-99]+/"){
    echo "visiting in Lobby"
} else {
   //is false, then it will not show the message
}
```

is correct?

How do I do it?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `preg_match`:

```
if (preg_match("/\bLobby-[0-9]{2}\b/i", $current_server)) {
    echo "visiting in Lobby";
}
else {
    // no message
}
```

### Demo

Comment: $match Where does the variable come from?

Comment: @FedeeMC PHP will create that variable as part of the call.  It would contain any matches/capture groups.  In your case, you may ignore it.

Comment: and if it was more than 100? Because I tried and it does not show the message with [0-999]

Comment: Please tell us what pattern you want to match.  Your question seems to imply that you expect two digits after `Lobby-`.  Is this not the case?